# Angular 12: angular converting Queryparams to encoded urls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, query-string

I recently did `ng update` and went then in problems. So basically I have a route `(/book)`
and a query param with:

> localhost:4200/book?success=true&successId=1

or

> localhost:4200/book?success=false&errorId=1

Angular is converting that to a single route, which is of course not registered in the
routing module:

> localhost:4200/book%3Fsuccess%3Dtrue&successId%3D1

My package.json:

```
{
"name": "frontend",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "~12.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.1",
    "@js-temporal/polyfill": "^0.4.0",
    "@material/progress-indicator": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "flag-icons": "^6.0.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^13.1.2",
    "ngx-translate": "0.0.1-security",
    "npm": "^8.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
}
}
```

Comment: Would you like to elaborate more? Where do you call the route from, can you show the router link etc etc.. ? Thank you.

Comment: I think this is not ng update issue, the URL seems to be okay. Generally characters like =,? are replaced with ASCII Encoding.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: I do it with a redirect in the backend:
res.writeHead(302, { Location: `${dataController.redirectFrontendUrl}/book?success=true&quantity=${quantity}&sum=${quantity * dataController.payement.pricePerNight}` }) 
I also tried to to it with res.redirect() but its the same problem. 
My Route:  { path: 'book', component: BookComponent }
even if I go on the url with query parameters without the backend its not working.

Comment: Well it just go to the default 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of my app.routing.module:

before:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: CreateAccComponent },
  { path: 'book', component: BookComponent },
  { path: 'location', component: LocationComponent },
  { path: 'openings', component: OpeningsComponent },
  { path: 'pictures', component: PicturesComponent },
  { path: 'roomtour', component: RoomtourComponent },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminPanelComponent },
  { path: 'bookingProcess', component: BookingProcessComponent },
  { path: '**', component: DefaultComponent}
];
```

after:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: CreateAccComponent },
  { path: 'book', component: BookComponent },
  { path: 'location', component: LocationComponent },
  { path: 'openings', component: OpeningsComponent },
  { path: 'pictures', component: PicturesComponent },
  { path: 'roomtour', component: RoomtourComponent },
  { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: AdminPanelComponent },
  { path: 'bookingProcess', component: BookingProcessComponent }
];
```

since I removed the path: '**' it works just as expected!